# Enabling UseNUMA flag for hadoop?

Tags: java, bash, hadoop, flags, numa

I wish to enable UseNUMA flag for my hadoop framework which uses java.

The problem is I don't know which all places java command has been called by hadoop framework.

So, I've written alias for java command in `/etc/bash.bashrc` as

```
alias java='java -XX:+UseNUMA'
```

Is it the right way to do it?

How will I know  if the flag is turned on or not? I mean can check this using following command

```
# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep UseNUMA
```

But how to check if hadoop is using it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an alias in bashrc won't be useful. Hadoop uses the environment variable JAVA_HOME for locating java home, java command is taken from the path ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java. So even if you create an alias in your .bashrc, will be useless.

For specifying JVM flags during hadoop daemon's starts, make use of the configuration file /hadoop-env.sh specify the flags in the environment variable.

```
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-XX:+UseNUMA -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-XX:+UseNUMA -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-XX:+UseNUMA -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS="-XX:+UseNUMA -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS"
export HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS="-XX:+UseNUMA -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS"
```

Enabling the same in Client side while executing the co like hadoop,yarn,mapred use the following environment variable

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-XX:+UseNUMA"
```

For checking the flag is enabled or not, following command can be used.

```
ps aux | grep hadoop
```